# Bootstrap (frontend) + ngMaterial (backend) together in Angular-Meteor app?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

Is there any way to load JS selectively depending on module?

I want to have Bootstrap.css included in templates that are in frontend and Angular Material for temaplates that are in backend of my app.

Currently if I import `bootstrap.css` in one component it's loaded globally which I don't want. This also means that `backend.css` and  `ngMaterial` will also be loaded in frontend components...

Answer (score 0):

So the way to conditionally load CSS I came up with is not very elegant but works.

I'm using Angular UI Router and when it comes to resolve route I append/remove `link` tag with CSS sheet using `angular.element()`. In my case it's abstract routes for backend and frontend, therefore it resolves (and appends/removes) link tag only once when browsing children routes.

```
// Frontend - add Bootstrap

$stateProvider
.state('front', {
    url: "",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl,
    resolve: {
        importBootstrapCss() {
            let head = angular.element(document.querySelector('head'));
            head.append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' id='bootstrap-css'>");
        }
    }
});

// Backend - remove Bootstrap

$stateProvider
.state('backend', {
    url: "/backend",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl,
    resolve: {
        deleteBootstrapCss() {
            let link = angular.element(document.getElementById('bootstrap-css'));
            link.remove();
        }
    }
});
```